Issues with DependsOnMethod in TestNG After Upgrading
I have a test suite organized into multiple classes based on functionality. For example:

ClassA contains the createBooking test method m1.
ClassB contains the modifyBooking test method m2, which depends on m1.
ClassC contains the cancelBooking test method m3, which also depends on m1.

Here's a simplified example:
class ClassA { 
    @Test 
    public void m1() {
        createBooking logic
    }
}

class ClassB { 
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"com.package.ClassA.m1"})
    public void m2() { 
        modifyBooking logic 
    }
} 

class ClassC { 
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"com.package.ClassA.m1"})
    public void m3() {
        cancelBooking logic 
    }
}

This setup was working fine with TestNG 7.5.1. However, after upgrading TestNG, I'm facing the following issues:  DependsOnMethod is partially working: m2 waits for m1 to complete, but if m1 fails, m2 still executes, which is not the expected behavior. If m1 fails, m2 should be skipped because it depends entirely on m1. The testng-failed.xml file should contain all three methods (m1, m2, and m3).
Attempted Solutions:

Using dependsOnGroups instead of dependsOnMethods:  This does not include dependent methods in the testng-failed.xml file.
Using both dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups together:  This works as expected but feels redundant and not ideal.

Could anyone suggest a better approach or guide me on how to raise this issue with the TestNG team so it can be fixed in upcoming versions?

This sounds like a regression bug that got introduced as a result of this PR https://github.com/testng-team/testng/pull/2699. Can you please file a bug at https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues
